# Why doesn't Perl support interpolation of hashes in double quotes?

Tags: perl, hash, interpolation

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my %hash=("no1"=>1, 
        "no2"=>2,
      );

print %hash; #Prints no11no22
print "%hash"; #Prints %hash
```

Why doesn't Perl support interpolation of a hash within double quotes? It supports interpolation for scalars ($), arrays (@) then why not for hashes (%)?

Comment: I didn't think the Perl cookbook was freely available, legally

Comment: A workaround is to cast a hash to an array reference and then dereference it: `print "@{[%hash]}"`

Comment: @mob But is isn't a good workaround, consider the hash `my %h = ("foo bar" => "foo", "bar foo" => "foo")`.  You wouldn't be able to determine which were the keys and which were the values.  A better solution is to use some form of serialization like `YAML`, `JSON`, etc.

Comment: @Chas. Owens - meh. For array `@a=("foo","bar foo","bar");print "@a"` you can't tell where one element ends and the next one begins either.

Comment: @mob you replied after 2 years! haha :D

Comment: @mob Funny, I have no problem telling where they end: `$"=",";print "@a"`.  Of course, you could add some globals to control how the hash printed, but more globals are the last thing Perl needs, especially when serializing data to strings is a problem well solved by YAML, JSON, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How should a hash stringify?  Scalars are obvious and arrays too.  But what should a hash be?  How useful will such a stringification be?  Is it more or less useful than being able to use a % character unescaped in an interpolating string?  Is it worth the amount of work it will take to fix all of the code that uses % in interpolated strings today?

If you can come up with good answers to these questions, then I am sure P5P would be willing to listen to them.

Comment: I am little surprised that interpolation of hashes is considered vastly different from those of arrays and is considered 'unneeded'. May I know why stringification of arrays is needed and that of hashes is not?

Comment: @Salil Stringification of arrays is needed for backwards compatibility.  If it could be removed from the language, it probably would be.  In fact, Perl 6 does not have array interpolation.  It has expressions interpolation instead, which works out much better: `"{ @a.join(',') }"` and `"{ %h.perl }"`.

Comment: "How should a hash stringify?" Other languages such as Java manage just fine.

Answer (score 21):

To quote Nathan Torkington: "The big problem is that % is heavily used in double-quoted strings with printf." More information is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120115075936/http://dev.perl.org/perl6/rfc/237.html).

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to the "why", but I thought I would point out various answers to the "how".

One could, of course, try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;

my %hash = (
    "no1" => 1,
    "no2" => 2,
);

print "@{[ %hash ]}\n";
```

But, I don't know what use that would be.

If you want to dump the contents of a hash or any other complicated data structure, use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) or [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAML) or [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/JSON) depending on your use case.

Comment: Check the Chas. Owens's comment on my question.

Comment: Ooops! I missed that comment. I think I am going to leave this answer up in case others miss the comment as well.

Comment: You could always say `"@{[ map { "$_ => $hash{$_}\n" } keys %hash]}"`, but that is a little silly.