# Perl variable interpolation rules for %vars versus $vars

Tags: perl, string-interpolation

Even though it is in double quotes, and `%s` should be interpolated to a non-existent hash, this is valid Perl and outputs `"confusing = true"`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $what = "confusing = %s";
printf $what, "true";
```

However, this is not valid (as expected), because $s does not exist:

```
my $what = "confusing = $s";
```

Comment: Quite related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731291/why-doesnt-perl-support-interpolation-of-hashes-in-double-quotes

Comment: Thanks pilcrow. I will take Nathan Torkington's quote as an answer.  "The big problem is that % is heavily used in double-quoted strings with printf."

Comment: @pilcrow Not related; note that this is a call to `printf`, which handles `%s` in its format string in a specific, defined fashion, not a call to `print`, in which `%s` is questionable and Torkington's dictum applies.

Comment: @AaronMiller, the OP's true question concerns the semantics of what appears to be a variable in one double-quoted string (`"%s"`) vs. what appears to be a variable in another double-quoted string (`"$s"`).  What the OP does with the strings — using them as arguments to printf, etc. — is not material.

Comment: @pilcrow Of course it is! `printf` interprets `%s`, and gives it behavior which for anyone familiar with that function is entirely expected; `print` doesn't, and gives it behavior which someone not deeply familiar with Perl is likely to find surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say *"`%s` should be interpolated to a non-existent hash"* but it shouldn't. There is no hash interpolation. It is possible in Perl 6 though.

Answer (score 4):

Also, hashes are not interpolated in double-quotes; scalars (including hash elements) and arrays are.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a format specifier and a value to `printf`, and it's behaving as intended; this may look like a hash interpolation, but it isn't.

See `perldoc -f sprintf` for details on format specifiers; in short, `%s` in the format specifier indicates that a value should be interpolated as a string, the effect being identical in this case to `print "confusing = $what"`.

If you replace `printf` with `print`, the `%s` will be taken literally, rather than as a variable interpolation, and the result will be `confusing = %s`; this, and not a call to `printf`, is the case in which Torkington's dictum applies.